# JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, object

I want to create several objects that are local to a specific function, but I want another function to act as a helper. The purpose of the helper function is to reduce the amount of duplicate code (there will eventually be many objects created as the script progresses).

I 'boiled down' my script, made sure it works, and then copy/pasted it below. The function named 'foo' works (there is an php file not shown for the jQuery/ajax call). However, I want the ajax call to be in the getNode function (the helper function) and preferably the setting of a temporary object also in getNode. My thinking is that a temporary object could be passed to foo from getNode.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Node() {
        this.nodeId;
        this.type;  //can be used for diferent shapes, color cobinations, etc.
        this.text;
    }

    function getNode(id){
        $.post("updateDB.php", send, function(theResponse){ 
            var responseArray = theResponse.split(',');
            ....?
    }

    function foo(id){
        var centerNode = new Node();
        var send = 'id=' + id + '&action=getNode';
        $.post("updateDB.php", send, function(theResponse){ 
            var responseArray = theResponse.split(',');
            centerNode.nodeId = responseArray[0];
            centerNode.type = responseArray[1];
            centerNode.text = responseArray[2];         
            alert('nodeId' + centerNode.nodeId);
            alert('node type' + centerNode.type);
            alert('node text' + centerNode.text);
        });                 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <a onclick="foo(5)">test</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to provide a callback to `getNode`:

```
function getNode(id, callback){
    $.post("updateDB.php", send, function(theResponse){ 
        var responseArray = theResponse.split(',');
        var node = new Node();
        node.nodeId = responseArray[0];
        node.type = responseArray[1];
        node.text = responseArray[2];         
        callback(node);
    });
}
```

EDIT: "How would `foo` be setup?"

So in the example, `foo` is to respond to the click event by getting the node object and then alerting it's data. That is my understanding. If `getNode` were defined as above:

```
function foo(id) {
  getNode(id, function(node) {
    alert('nodeId' + node.nodeId);
    alert('node type' + node.type);
    alert('node text' + node.text);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and so  I was just Googling 'callbacks' to see how I could use this.  How would 'foo' need to be set up?

Comment: callbacks are the awesome/terrible feature of javascript. In fact you need them, because the language is asynchronous. In your original example at the time you call `foo`, there is no `theResponse` data. That has yet to be populated by the ajax post callback. In my version of the `getNode` function I'm chaining the ajax callback into the `foo` callback. It's kind of hard to describe, so I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well boiling your question down to the essentials (I want local variables to be available in separate functions):

1. You can pass the objects to the helper function.
2. You can create a class and put both functions in it and make the function locals global to the class.

These are the only ways I can think of at the moment.

JS Classes example:

```
function ClassName(vars){
    //This is used to init the class and is called when you use var myClass = new ClassName();
    //example: this.varName = this.functionName();
    //Instead of using prototype (will see latter in this example) you could just define the function/vars in here like (which would make them private to this class):
    //this.functionName = function(vars){};
}

ClassName.prototype.functionName = function(vars){}  //Out hear makes these var/functions publicly accessible
ClassName.prototype.varName = 5;
```

And then to use it:

```
var myClass = new ClassName(vars);
myClass.functionName(vars);
```

So put your local variables and your helper function inside the constructor to make them private and your other function as a prototype to make it publicly accessible.